# Author information on non-title page

Tags: titles

I would like to add author information on a page which is not the title page.

Something like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}
    \date{}
    \maketitle


    \chapter{New Chapter}
    Authors

    Institutions
\end{document}
```

The author information will need to go on a chapter page underneath the chapter heading.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is `\maketitle` still doing what you want in this example? That is, you just want to access the `\author` macro for a second time?

Comment: @jon thats correct

Comment: Wil there be different authors for each chapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of `\maketitle` is to delete the values entered in `\title`, `\author` and `\date`. You can capture these before its removed using the code below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \let\printtitle\@title
  \let\printauthor\@author
  \let\printdate\@date
  \oldmaketitle
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{A chapter}

Title: \printtitle \par
Author: \printauthor \par
Date: \printdate

\end{document}
```

The following - storing the content in macros that you can access later - is an equivalent alternative:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{A title}
\newcommand{\myauthor}{An author}
\newcommand{\mydate}{\today}

\title{\mytitle}
\author{\myauthor}
\date{\mydate}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{A chapter}

Title: \mytitle \par
Author: \myauthor \par
Date: \mydate

\end{document}
```